# Grabbing the value of an input range with php

Tags: php

I am trying to grab the value attribute off of this input range using PHP. This is what the input range looks like:

```
<input type = 'range' name = 'volsettings 'list='volsettings' min='0' max='100' value='7' oninput='outputUpdate(value)'>
```

I have tried to use the DOMDocument and use getAttribute based off what I have seen from other answers, but for some reason can't get it to work(it says that it is a non-object) what I have tried so far to grab the value attribute is shown below:

```
$htmlDom = new DOMDocument();
$htmlDom->loadHTML("mypage.php");
$domPath = new DOMXpath($htmlDOM);
$nodes = $domPath->query('//input[@name="volsettings"]');
$node = $nodes->item(0);
$volume= $node->getAttribute('value');
echo $volume;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note, that [DOMDocument::loadHTML](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) function ***parses the HTML contained in the string***:

```
$htmlStr = "<input type = 'range' name = 'volsettings' list='volsettings' min='0' max='100' value='7' oninput='outputUpdate(value)'>";

$htmlDom = new \DOMDocument();
$htmlDom->loadHTML($htmlStr);
$domPath = new \DOMXpath($htmlDom);
$nodes = $domPath->query('//input[@name="volsettings"]/@value');
$val = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

print_r($val);  // prints: 7
```

`//input[@name="volsettings"]/@value` - specific xpath location path to retrieve `value` attribute

---

To load html content from file use [DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php) function.